# Access a namespace

Tags: python, namespaces

I've added another folder into my project so I can pull methods from files in another project. I did this with the first 3 lines

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/another/dir')

from file_methods import load_object

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("path")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args['path'])
```

When doing simple argparse, I'm getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_pupil_data.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(args['path'])
TypeError: 'Namespace' object is not subscriptable
```

How do I access this namespace?

Answer (score 3):

There is *no dictionary-like access to the parsed arguments*. Use a dot notation ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-parse-args-method)):

```
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.path)
```